# Awk - Control when my $# variables are expanded to merge two files with variable number of columns

Tags: bash, awk

My bash script is calling a awk script that nicely merges two files

```
mapfieldfile1=1
mapfieldfile2=2
awk  -v FS="\t" 'BEGIN {OFS="\t"}
                                FNR==NR{hash1['"\$${mapfieldfile2}"']=$1 FS $3 FS $4 FS $5 FS $6;next}
                ('"\$${mapfieldfile1}"' in hash1){ print $0, hash1['"\$${mapfieldfile1}"']}' file2 file1
```

However I want to a more general version,where I don't have to hardcode the columns that I want to print, I simply want to print everything but my id column. Replacing *$1 FS $3 FS $4 FS $5 FS $6* for $0 "almost" does the work, except that repeats the id column. I have been trying to dynamically create a a string similar to the *$1 FS $3 FS $4 FS $5 FS $6* but I am getting literally the *$1 $3 $4 $5 $6* strings in the merged file, as opposed to expanding their values. Also, smaller side effects: I am adding a tab in the middle and losing some headers, below is the code and example files.
I would like to find the solution to my merge and also understand what I am doing wrong and why my variables are not expanding.

I appreciate any help!

```
mapfieldfile1=1
mapfieldfile2=2
awk  -v FS="\t" 'BEGIN {OFS="\t";strfields=""}
                        FNR==NR{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) if(i!='"${mapfieldfile2}"') {strfields=strfields" "FS"  $"i};
                                hash1['"\$${mapfieldfile2}"']=strfields;strfields="";next}
                        ('"\$${mapfieldfile1}"' in hash1){print $0, hash1['"\$${mapfieldfile1}"']}' file2 file1


$cat file1 
sampleid        s1      s2      s3      s4
1       1       1       1       1
2       2       2       2       2
3       3       3       3       3
4       4       4       4       4
$cat file2 
a0      sampleid        a1      a2      a3      a4
a0      1       a       a       a       a4
a0      2       b       b       b       a4
a0      3       c       c       c       a4
a0      5       e       e       e       a4
$cat first_code_result.txt (good one!)
sampleid        s1      s2      s3      s4      a0      a1      a2      a3      a4
1       1       1       1       1       a0      a       a       a       a4
2       2       2       2       2       a0      b       b       b       a4
3       3       3       3       3       a0      c       c       c       a4
$cat second_code_result.txt
sampleid        s1      s2      s3      s4                $1      $3      $4      $5      $6
1       1       1       1       1                 $1      $3      $4      $5      $6
2       2       2       2       2                 $1      $3      $4      $5      $6
3       3       3       3       3                 $1      $3      $4      $5      $6
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this (untested):

```
awk -v mf1="$mapfieldfile1" -v mf2="$mapfieldfile2" '
BEGIN {FS=OFS="\t"}
FNR==NR{sub(/\t[^\t]+/,""); hash1[$mf2]=$0; next}
($mf1 in hash1){ print $0, hash1[$mf1]}
' file2 file1
```

Don't let shell variables expand within awk scripts, use a regexp to remove fields from the record and idk why the script you haven't shown us is printing literally `$3`, etc. but you must be including them in a string. You'd have to post that script for help debugging it.

Check where mf1 vs mf2 should appear, I got confused reading your scripts.

EDIT - I had to tweak it as above I was deleting $2 before using it:

```
$ awk -v mf1="1" -v mf2="2" '
BEGIN {FS=OFS="\t"}
FNR==NR{key=$mf2; sub(/\t[^\t]+/,""); hash1[key]=$0; next}
($mf1 in hash1){ print $0, hash1[$mf1]}
' file2 file1
sampleid    s1  s2  s3  s4  a0  a1  a2  a3  a4
1   1   1   1   1   a0  a   a   a   a4
2   2   2   2   2   a0  b   b   b   a4
3   3   3   3   3   a0  c   c   c   a4
```

Note that the sub() above relies on the key field being $2 and FS being a tab. If you need a more general solution let us know.

Here's a version that'll do what you want for any key field values and will work in any awk, it just requires the FS to be a tab or some other fixed string (i.e. not a regexp):

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS=OFS="\t" }
NR==FNR {
    key = $mf2
    val = ""
    nf = 0
    for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
        if (i != mf2) {
            val = (nf++ ? val FS : "") $i
        }
    }
    hash1[key] = val
    next
}
$mf1 in hash1 { print $0, hash1[$mf1] }

$ awk -v mf1="1" -v mf2="2" -f tst.awk file2 file1
sampleid    s1  s2  s3  s4  a0  a1  a2  a3  a4
1   1   1   1   1   a0  a   a   a   a4
2   2   2   2   2   a0  b   b   b   a4
3   3   3   3   3   a0  c   c   c   a4
```

Comment: Thanks Ed, I checked the mf1 and mf2 and tested your code in different ways and I didn't get my desired output. Sorry If my description wasn't clear enough. I am not expanding the shell variable within the awk, I closed the awk (single quote), expand the shell variable and reopen the awk. It is just concatenating things. But I see how that is confusing and parameters like your example are much clear. I didnt show printing literally $2 because is the key column (in file2), $3 I showed. Thanks again.

Comment: @ecolog I understand what you are doing and it IS expanding the shell variables to become part of the awk script. Never do that, it introduces potential bugs, bizarre behavior, and crypit error messages (if you're lucky!). See http://cfajohnson.com/shell/cus-faq-2.html#Q24 for the right way to use the **value of** shell variables inside awk scripts. The problem with your question is it discusses HOW you are trying to do something but never clearly states WHAT you are trying to do. If we're supposed to figure out the WHAT by reading the scripts and examples YMMV...

Comment: Thanks Ed, I will definitely replace that practice for parameters in the future. I in fact changed my scripts to parameters and it is not making a difference in my particular case. I know joining two files is a simple task, my main goal is to build dynamically the key `$1 FS $3 FS $4 FS $5 FS $6` and have them expanded later by awk. I am surprised I couldn't do that. In my harcoded case it's working fine. I think there are some concepts of scope or compilation order or variables types that I must not be understanding well.

Comment: My script shows you how to do that - the sub() deletes the $2 value and leaves the rest as-is so you're left with what you wanted, i.e. `$1 FS $3 FS $4 FS $5 FS $6`. Are you SURE the script doesn't do exactly what you want? I've reread your question and best I can tell it seems like it should. In what way does it not do what you want?

Comment: I see what the problem was, I was deleting $2 before using it as the hash index! See the updated (and tested!) answer.

Comment: Oh great. This is good. Can you tell me in simple words how `sub(/\t[^\t]+/,"")` is removing $2. And yes, how can we make it general as my mf2 is a parameter to the script that could change, it could be any integer value corresponding at one of the existing columns of file2. FS will always be tab.

Comment: Your fields are tab-separated so the first tab in the file is between $1 and $2 and then the first string of non-tabs is the value of $1. So `sub(/\t[^\t]+/,"")` changes `$1<tab1>$2<tab2>$3` into `$1<tab2>$3`. Does the solution have to work for any FS or just for tabs? Would you be happy with a GNU awk specific solution? Most things are simpler in gawk...

Comment: I added a portable solution.

Comment: This is fantastic. Make sense. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

if your files are sorted already, the default output of `join` is what you want

```
$ join -t$'\t' -11 -22 file1 file2
sampleid        s1      s2      s3      s4      a0      a1      a2      a3     a4
1       1       1       1       1       a0      a       a       a       a4
2       2       2       2       2       a0      b       b       b       a4
3       3       3       3       3       a0      c       c       c       a4
```

or, after prettying with `column`

```
$ join -t$'\t' -11 -22 file1 file2 | column -t

sampleid  s1  s2  s3  s4  a0  a1  a2  a3  a4
1         1   1   1   1   a0  a   a   a   a4
2         2   2   2   2   a0  b   b   b   a4
3         3   3   3   3   a0  c   c   c   a4
```